# Same DataTemplate for different view

Tags: uwp-xaml, winui-3, winui

I have view1.xaml:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Item" x:DataType="viewmodels:itemVM">
    <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind text, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Loaded="Text_Loaded" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<ListView x:Name="listview"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}"/>
```

If I have view2.xaml using the same DataTemplate of view1:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Item" x:DataType="viewmodels:itemVM">
    <Grid>
          <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind text, Mode=OneWay}"
                            Loaded="Text_Loaded" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<FlipView x:Name="flipview"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}"/>
```

But I don't want to duplicate the code in view (DataTemplate) as well as the code-behind(for Loaded="Text_Loaded"), so what is the solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the DataTemplate into a **ResourceDictionary File**, when you need to use it, just add the ResourceDictionary File to the Resources of the page.

Also, you could bind the loading event to a command of the ViewModel. Then you don't need to write the event too many times.

I made a simple demo here and you could follow it. Here is the steps first:

1. Create a new `ResourceDictionary File` in your project, name it whatever you want. Put the `DateTemplate` into the ResourceDictionary File.
2. Add the reference of `ResourceDictionary File` to the App.Xaml, then you could use it anywhere in your app.
3. In the Solution Explorer panel, right click on your project name and select **Manage NuGet Packages**. In the NuGet Package Manager, select the `Browse` tab and search for `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed`.Then install it.
4. Change the `DataTemplate` with Xaml behavior so that you could bind the loaded event to a command of the ViewModel.

Here is the code

**Dictionary1.xaml** - the ResourceDictionary File

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:local="using:TestTemplate"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:Interactions="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core">

<DataTemplate x:Key="Item">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="Block" Text="{Binding text, Mode=OneWay}">
             <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                 <!--when the event triggers, call the command of the ViewModel-->
                 <Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Loaded">
                     <Interactions:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding VM_Loaded}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=Block}"/>
                 </Interactions:EventTriggerBehavior>
             </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

**App.Xaml:**

```
    <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

**MainPage.xaml：**

```
 <Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listview" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Item}"/>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel:**

```
   public class itemVM
{

    public string text { get; set; }

    public ICommand VM_Loaded
    {
        get
        {
            return new CommadEventHandler<TextBlock>((s) => this.loaded(s));
        }
    }

    private void loaded(TextBlock element)
    {
        try
        {
            element.Text = "Test";
            Debug.WriteLine("loaded");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}


public class CommadEventHandler<T> : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public Action<T> action;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.action((T)parameter);
    }
    public CommadEventHandler(Action<T> action)
    {
        this.action = action;

    }
}
```